# Ширина блока, внутри которого сетка из float'ов по размеру контента

Tags: html, css, float

Столкнулся с проблемой при верстке. Мне нужна сетка маленьких блоков, при помощи float или просто inline-block прижатых с левому краю, а сама сетка должна быть всегда прижата к правому. Т.е. ширина внешнего блока всегда должна оставаться равной ширине контента. Это можно сделать, например, назначив ей тот же inline-block, но проблема в том, что когда количество 
внутренних блоков становиться таким, что они не умещаются в одну строчу и переходят на следующую, ширина внешнего блока становиться равной 100%, соответственно увеличивается отступ крайнего правого маленького блока, от правого края экрана. Должна всегда оставаться одинаковой. Можно ли как-то без js хаков сделать такую всегда прижатую к правому краю сетку?

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div style="float:right"></div>
  <div style="float:right"></div>
  <div style="float:right"></div>
  <div style="float:right"></div>
</div>
```

[image: проблема]

Вот. На первой картинке то, что нужно: блок, чья ширина зависит от ширины экрана, с сеткой внутри, всегда прижатой к правому краю.
На второй и третей проблемы.
P.S. на рисунке колонок 5, но может быть сколько угодно в зависимости от ширины внешнего блока.

Comment: Почему не Flex?

Comment: А как именно это можно сделать при помощи flex'а? Я пробовал, у меня возникали все те же проблемы.

Comment: Вы дополните свой вопрос картинкой (или схемой), где будет понятно, где какое нужно выравнивание. Тогда сможете получить точный ответ. В любом случае для сеток лучше использовать flex, а про float забыть как страшный сон. :)

Answer (score 0):

А как-то так не пойдет? Ибо я не до конца понял суть вопроса, разберемся по ходу дела :)

```css
.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 20px;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 150px;
}
.cont>div {
  width: calc(100% * (1/5) - 10px);
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Пробовал что-то похожее. Тут минус в том, что независимо от ширины экрана у тебя 5 колонок в сетке. Нужно чтобы количество колонок коррелировало с шириной блока cont.

Comment: @Nik по вашему примеру и описанию я понял что вам нужно что бы cont принимал ширину содержимого. При этом на всех примерах я увидел что у вас 5 блоков в ряд, так что я предположил что так и нужно.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: @Nik А почему контент должен не помещаться в блок если ширина того равна ширине контента?

Comment: Потому-что ширина блока не выравнивается по ширине контента. Если, скажем, задаешь фиксированную ширину блока, то, как только у тебя несколько строк блоков, ширина внешнего становиться 100%